# Exception in laravel 5.8 : Trying to get property of non-object when trying to edit data

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Recently I've started with Laravel 5.8 and I'm trying to make the edit button which will update the row from the database. and when the edit button click, Laravel raise an error like this

[image]

this is my Controller:

```php
    public function edit($id_book){
        $book = Books::find($id_book);
        return view('/books',['book'->$book]);
    }

    public function UploadEdit(Request $request){
        DB::table('books')->where('id_book',$request->id_book)->update([
            'judul' => $request->judul,
            'gambar' => $request->gambar,
            'kategori' => $request->kategori,
            'deskripsi' => $request->deskripsi,
            'ketersediaan' => $request->ketersediaan,
            'lokasi' => $request->lokasi
        ]);

        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

this is my models:

```php
    class Books extends Model
    {
        protected $table = "books";
        protected $primaryKey = "id_book";

       protected $fillable = [
           'judul',
           'gambar',
           'kategori',
           'deskripsi',
           'ketersediaan',
           'lokasi'
       ];
    }
```

I was trying to solve this problem with change edit function in the controller:
from this

```php
    public function edit($id_book){
        $book = Books::find($id_book);
        return view('/books',['book'->$book]);
    }
```

to this

```php
    public function edit($id_book){
        $book = Books::find($id_book);
        return view('/books',compact('book'));
    }
```

and this:

```php
    public function edit($id_book){
         $book = Books::find($id_book);
         return view('/books')->withBooks('$book');
    }
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: var_dump($id_book) and check result first

Comment: look like normal

Answer (score 1):

I think error shows `id_book` is wrong.
You should use `findOrFail()` method.

```
public function edit($id_book){
    $book = Books::findOrFail($id_book);
    return view('/books',compact('book'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your line 58 (`edit()` function's return statement) to:

```
return view('/books',compact('book'));
```

Comment: still doesn't work friend, but thank you for your advice

Comment: No but now, variable books undefined in my views @Qumber Rizvi

Comment: You can simply change that variable to match the one you are returning from the controller. In my answer, it is `$book`, not `$books`. @zer0sign

Answer (score 0):

It seems you used `->` instead `=>`  to assign value

**Change**

```
return view('/books',['book'->$book]);
```

**to**

```
return view('/books',['book' => $book]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 public function edit($id_book){
        $book = Books::where('id_book', $id_book)->first();
        return view('/books', compact('book'));
    }
```

Comment: Not a primary key issue. You can see that in the dump. Collection is received and assigned onto $book. https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCfZ1.png

Comment: May be  edit page view not found, can you tell me what is your edit view name

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public function edit($id_book) {
   $book = Book::find($id_book);

   return view('books.edit', compact('book'));
}
```